# JSON Parser when sending body through HTTP Post using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, json, puppeteer

so currently i want to send a post request to my api using puppeteer. Here's my code

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        //resultFromCrawl.map(value => {
        //const cac = JSON.stringify(resultFromCrawl[0])
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
            // Here, is where you change the request method and 
            // add your post data
        var data = {
             'method': 'POST',
             'postData':  queryString.stringify(JSON.stringify(resultFromCrawl[0])),
             'headers': {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
       };
    
       interceptedRequest.continue(data);
});
const response = await page.goto(`http:my-url-post/post`)
const responseBody = await response.text();
```

So i got an error at jackson parser as response from server

```
JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): Expected space separating root-level values; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
```

My object is ( resultFromCrawl[0] )

```
 {
  alias: 'some-thing-some-thing',
  title: 'Some thing some thing',
  date: '15:21 | 23/01/2021',
  publicationTime: 1611386441332,
  excerpt: 'some thing some thing',
  status: 'PUBLISHED',
  url: 'some url',
  composingType: 'Tự viết',
  type: 'Bài',
  penName: 'Nam',
  featuredImage: 'someImage',
  websiteId: 'websiteId',
  authorId: 'authorId',
  categoryId: 'cateId',
  isFeatured: false,
  seo: {
    metaDescription: '',
    metaImage: '',
    metaSameArticle: true,
    metaTitle: '',
    ogDescription: '',
    ogImage: '',
    ogSameArticle: true,
    ogTitle: ''
  },
  postContent: '<html>Html stuff here</html>'
}
```

Any ideas guys? Or have i parse wrong anything? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

What a dumb f am i.
Simply remove the queryString in postData:
'postData': JSON.stringify(resultFromCrawl[0])
And we're good to go